# Adjusted $R^2$ & F test are not shown in regression with robust standard errors in Stata

Tags: regression, stata, r-squared, f-test, robust-standard-error

The adjusted $R^2$ is not shown when a regression with robust standard errors is calculated in Stata.
This is surprising to me since the value of the $R^2$ is unaffected in regressions with robust standard errors.

Is there any statistical reason for not quoting the adjusted $R^2$ when using robust standard errors in regression?

Furthemore if I add more variables  the F test disappears.(e.g. with 9 variables it shows but not with 13), Is this for the same reason? How can we report such results and deal with this issue?

Answer (score 12):

If you specify the `robust` option, you are telling Stata that you don't really believe the errors are homoskedastic. There are several implications:

- The sums of squared residuals are still used to drive the estimation (you minimize them).
- As every observation has its own variance, the sum of the squared errors is no longer distributed as a $\chi^2$, and the ratios of the model and residual sums of squares are no longer distributed as an $F$.
- Since different observations contribute different amount of information, there isn't any way now to correct $R^2$ for the prognostic value the way $R^2_{\rm adj}$ does: one observation $\neq$ one degree of freedom.

Essentially, as the notion of variance is not quite applicable to the dependent variable (do you want to talk about the conditional variance of $Y$, i.e., the variance of the error terms, which, as we said, is not constant any more; or do you want to talk about the total variance, which, inconveniently, depends on the distribution of the explanatory variables), the whole concept of $R^2$ starts breaking down in its meaning.

Comment: Plus adjusted R2 is a horrible thing.

Comment: This is a normative judgement, @JeremyMiles. Obviously, a lot of people expect to see it... and also want to see it in Poisson and logistic regression, as well.

Comment: @StasK On the same logic, the $R^2$ is shown but. Its only the adjusted $R^2$ which is not shown. And so is the F-test.  So technically, when I report the data in this case, show I report the $R^2$ (ignoring the adjusted $R^2$?). How am I to report the data given I'm using the robust se.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Explain why you think so.

Comment: [According to this post](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2004-05/msg00107.html) which I have just found, "the F statistic, for instance, is no longer based on sums of squares; it becomes a Wald test based on the robustly estimated variance matrix" (is this correct?).  What is puzzling is that the $R^2$  is still shown.

Comment: @CesareCamestre - not a horrible thing - I overstated, but not a useful thing. We don't correct most things to make them into population effects. Unless you have a pretty small sample, and/or a really large number of variables, the adjustment is tiny. Adjusted R-squared can be negative, which makes no sense.

Comment: @StasK I have added a further question on the f-test, in this discussion rather than posting a new post because its related.  Would appreciate feedback.

Comment: @StasK I thought that $R^2$ is simply an algebraic description of explained variance -- does it actually require the assumption of homoskedasticity? In deriving $R^2$ I did not think that it's necessary.

Comment: With homoskedastic data, things are clear. With heteroskedastic data, you have to start hesitating whether you have fixed or random regressors, as then your computation of the total and explained variances may differ (the latter making things more complicated). Stata simply protects you from using the numbers that don't have a good justification... unlike Some Alternative Software that would easily produce a chi-square of 10^8 in a non-significant regression in a sample of size 100 if that's what your weights sum up to.

Comment: +1, but I don't understand this: "or do you want to talk about the total variance, which, inconveniently, depends on the distribution of the explanatory variables." Var(Y) doesn't depend on the distribution of the explanatory variables; and Var(Yhat) is pinned down by the point estimates and the distributions of the explanatory variables. Relatedly, your last comment doesn't quite make sense to me, I'm not sure what "fixed vs random regressors" means. Don't regressors have to be looked at as random variables for Var(Yhat) to make sense?