# evaluate the prediction power of a signal to predict a stock price

Tags: predictive-models

How would you evaluate the predictive power of a Signal time series (supposedly output by an Artificial Intelligence system) in predicting a stock price time series given a sample data set as follows:

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Adj Close | Signal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202106-01 | 627.80 | 633.80 | 620.55 | 620.55 | 623.90 | 85.11 |
| 2021-06-02 | 620.13 | 623.36 | 599.14 | 620.13 | 605.12 | 76.59 |
| 2021-06-03 | 601.80 | 604.55 | 571.22 | 571.22 | 572.84 | 68.73 |
| 2021-06-04 | 579.71 | 600.61 | 577.20 | 600.61 | 599.05 | 78.47 |
| 2021-06-07 | 591.83 | 610.00 | 582.88 | 610.00 | 605.13 | 78.63 |

and so on for some few weeks. No further information is provided.

**Question**: how could one evaluate the predictive power of Signal in predicting the stock price, given only the information above?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Please decide which particular question you want us to address and edit your post to focus on it.  I would suggest the first, because the second is so broad and non-specific that it just doesn't fit our format and guidelines.  Visit our [help] for more information about those.

Comment: For the first question, we can agree the interviewer could have given more information about how and when the signal was generated. Assuming the signal was generated at least the day before the stock price   , you could address a number of questions. For example, how well does the signal predict whether  the market on the following day goes up or down? (Correct 3 out of 4 in your data extract). Alternatively, you could look at a simple regression model with the signal as the independent variable.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But the question is very clear "evaluate the predictive power of Signal in predicting the stock price". Not if Signal can predict if the market goes up or down or if Signal can predict one week in advance the average stock price or anything else.

Comment: at whuber, these are the questions asked in the interview. It does not make any sense and it is not useful for anyone that I change the questions so that they fit some guidelines. These are real questions from a real interview. 
I do not like them more than you do. And I have no clue how to answer them. Let me stress again that the interviewer refused to answer any clarification question about the problem. If anyone can provide some feedback thanks!

Comment: The regression model will do that: its R-squared value combined with F test.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt thank you for your reply. Very clear and precise. What I am looking for! Anyone has any other suggestion, please?

Comment: We are not a service to supply answers to interview questions.  The fact that you got asked a question in some setting does not make in on topic or suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very expert in data science and also by general knowledge of data science I have so far, I think the data is very small.

Although certain general data cleaning procedure that you can try in my opinion is

1. Outlier detection and removal. May be you can use IQR method to detect outlier and remove then or impute them with median.
2. May be if it make sense, you can see correlation among the columns. The close and Adj_close might be highly correlated, So they both might not be needed but this entirely depends upon the model that will be used. If Linear regression then have columns should not be correlated, if tree based then correlated columns are ok.
3. The Signal column is not in the scale of other columns. So you can scale all columns and bring them to similar range of values. This is beneficial for Linear Regression.
4. If there are few rows missing and the usecase does not allow for the rows to be missing then you can artifically create rows and impute the the values using median or last value or mean or interpolation.

Hopefully my answers will be of any help to you.

Comment: 1. is problematic. Please check [Is it OK to remove outliers from data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200534/is-it-ok-to-remove-outliers-from-data).